# My UV map for importing images is a total mess

Tags: uv, image

[image: Weird, overlapping, differing sizes UV map]

I am a Blender newb and I'm trying to import an image and apply it to the face of an object (a panel of a tradeshow booth), but when I try to apply the image to the right face, my UV map is a total mess.

Some sides are large, others are small, sides are overlapping others, it's just so weird and impossible to work with.

What is happening and how do I get it to stop? How do I get it to just show a simple, unfolded cube that I can easily align my image to one face of?

PS, the image I'm trying to apply looks weird, I just blurred it for confidentiality purposes.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Why not simply unwrap the cube again? You can use *UV > Smart UV project*.